# Нужен ли JDK и JVM и перед установкой среды разработки по-типу eclipse нужны ли они вообще?

Tags: java, jvm, jdk11

Начинающий программист не судите строго. 
Обязательно ли нужно и нужно ли вообще устанавливать JDK и JVM перед установкой Eclipse или какой-либо другой среды разработки?

Comment: Для работоспособности самой среды типа Eclipse или, например, IntelliJ IDEA нет, такой необходимости нет. А вот если речь идёт о самом процессе разработки по средствам этой среды, то да, для разработки необходимо наличие jdk.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря для чего Вы используете IDE. Сама IDE может работать и так.

Если же Вы собираетесь писать программы на Java, то без JDK не обойтись.